# AWS billing - how to view cost for load balancing instance aka ELB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, billing

### In brief

How to know the monthly cost of an Elastic Load Balancing instance?

### Full detail

My team is using an AWS Elastic Beanstalk instance, and we need to know how much it costs per month.

My google lead me to [this AWS page](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/pricing/) which suggests to view the **cost of EC2 and ELB**

> The principal costs for a web application will typically be for the Amazon EC2 instance(s) and for the Elastic Load Balancing

We can use [AWS Calculator](http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html) to get the monthly cost of an EC2 instance; though we CANNOT find out how to compute the cost for the ELB there ie. using the AWS Calculator.

My google search results as [this AWS page](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/classicloadbalancer/pricing/) which shows a way to compute the cost **manually i.e. basing on $0.025 per hour run, and $0.008 per GB of data transfer**. But what is the average number of hours and/or transferred data? Why not just have it in the calculator too?

> If the load balancer ended up transferring 100 GB of data over a 30 day period, the monthly charge would amount to $18 (or $0.025 per hour x 24 hours per day x 30 days x 1 load balancer) for the load balancer hours and $0.80 (or $0.008 per GB x 100 GB) for the data transferred through the load balancer, for a total monthly charge of $18.80.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about AWS billing and not about a specific programing question.

Comment: @DanFromGermany Hi Dan, you may also go to tens of other similar questions to vote to close too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-web-services+billing

Answer (score 3):

To see how much your services are costing you, [turn on Detailed Billing Reports](http://support.cloudcheckr.com/getting-started-with-cloudcheckr/preparing-your-aws-account/#enable_dbr). This will create highly detailed billing information, saved in files in Amazon S3.

You can also use the billing option in the management console to see high-level billing by service, but you'll need to turn on Detailed Billing to obtain more detail (and that detail is only available after Detailed Billing is activated).

See also:

- [Pricing for Classic Load Balancer](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/classicloadbalancer/pricing/)
- [Pricing for Application Load Balancer](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/applicationloadbalancer/pricing/)